# Add Basic Authorization header to some requests

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-security

I want to display a live mjpeg stream from a camera in my Spring-based web-application, and the camera requires basic authentication.

Since Chrome does not support authentication in urls anymore (see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150#c3), and I am using the webapp mostly on Android tablets with Chrome in a fullscreen/homescreen mode, I am in trouble.

The image tag, with embedded auth, which btw works in Firefox, would be like this:

`<img src="http://username:password@the.camera.local/video.mjpeg" />`

Is there a way with Spring to intercept the GET request for certain urls and add an `Authorization` header?

**Edit 1**

On the other hand, if I could manage to load the image url with an `jQuery` ajax-request, to which I can add username and password parameters.

Any hint on how to do that practically is welcomed.

**Edit 2**

In fact my initial question is flawed. The request for the image is done by the browser directly to the camera url, and thus can not be modified by Spring Security.

Probably the only solution is to load the image by Ajax.

Comment: As mentioned, in the webapp, I have a page which displays the live stream from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I think using spring security would solve your purpose.

For Ex:- you can mention in spring-security.xml file,for which url you want to implement this.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

     <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/video/*" access="ROLE_USER" />             
        <!-- Basic authentication -->
        <http-basic/>
    </http>     
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="test" password="test_pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>    
</beans:beans>
```

Configure **web.xml** for spring security and add the dependencies in **pom.xml** also.

Now when you try to access the resource /video/ ,for every succesful authentication,it would add Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

How can add basic authentication to some of the request? if i use  spring security will add header to all requests.